# Make an appropriate trigonometric substitution to rewrite the given integrand as an integrand in the angle $\theta$ containing no square roots.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

- Assume all trigonometric functions are positive.
- Remove all square roots.
- Do NOT Evaluate the integral completely.

My integral is:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{49+x^2}}{x^2}\,dx$$

The only substitution I'm aware of is $u$-substitution. Is it asking me to set $u =$ some trig function? I'm not aware of any trig identities that have a square root already in them, so how do I get rid of this one?

Comment: try $x=7\tan u$ and find a reason why it works, and try to find a general formula for similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) = 1$; you can manipulate this by dividing by $\sin^2(t)$ or $\cos^2(t)$ on every term. In addition, you could combine that with solving for one of the trig functions and introducing a square root there.

That being said, if applying the substitution $x = 7\tan(\theta) \implies \textrm{d}x = 7\sec^2(\theta)\ \textrm{d}\theta$, we have
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{49 + 49\tan^2(\theta)}}{49\tan^2(\theta)}\ 7\sec^2(\theta)\ \textrm{d}\theta$$

Diving the Pythagorean identity above by $\cos^2(t)$ gives $\tan^2(t) + 1 = \sec^2(t)$. Try applying that to the integrand and see what simplifies down.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Fixed that up for some clarification.